# Problema al retorno con Transición de elementos en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Siguiendo ese [tutorial Shared Element Activity](https://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition)
La transición funciona correctamente de `Actividad A` hacia `Actividad B` el retorno también

**values-21/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

**Definición de la transición**

A ambos `ImageView` asigno la propiedad `android:transitionName="profile"`

**Inicio de transición**
Llamo actividad B con

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra(ActivityB.ARG_ITEM_ID, idItem);

ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
      makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, mThumbnail, "profile");
                ActivityCompat.startActivity(context, intent, options.toBundle());
```

**Problema**
El problema es cuando se está en la actividad B, si se rota el dispositivo al querer volver atrás no hace la transición correctamente (parpadea un poco y hace un fundido sin mas).

Entiendo es por el contexto, que Android al rotar el dispositivo estando en B y querer volver a la actividad A, como que la actividad A no se había creado con esa orientación no sabe realizar la transición.

¿Se puede solventar de alguna manera?
O bien detectar que si se gira el terminal pues desactivar el retorno usando transición de elementos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solventado de esa manera:

En `ActividadB` pongo una bandera para saber si el dispositivo se ha rotado o bien está en la misma orientación inicial.

Y luego al detectar volver atrás, se hace la transición inversa o un cierre normal.

```
...
private static boolean mOrientationChanged;
...

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mOrientationChanged = false;
    } else {
        mOrientationChanged = true;
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onback mOrientationChanged: " + mOrientationChanged);
    if (mOrientationChanged) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setSharedElementReturnTransition(null);
            finish();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    } else {
        super.supportFinishAfterTransition();
    }
    //super.onBackPressed();
}
```